# How to use Chebyshev's inequality or the law of large numbers to a probability question?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, inequality, law-of-large-numbers

Let $x$ be a random bit string that takes values $\{1,0\}^n$. Let $r$ be the value of the most significant bit (MSB) of $x$ (and $r$ is a r.v. $1$ or $0$ that are equally likely). Let $g$ be our guess for the MSB of $x$. The guess $g$ is a r.v. representing that we somehow guess that value of $r$ for the bit string $x$. The method of guessing is left unspecified but we know some probability facts about it.

It is given that we guess the value of $r$ with the following probability:
$$\Pr[r=g] > \frac12 +\alpha.$$
Let $p_0$ be the probability that we guess it to be $1$ (i.e., $g=1$) given $r$ is $0$, and $p_1$ be the probability that we guess it correctly given $r$ is $1$:
$$p_0 = \Pr[g=1|r=0]$$
$$p_1 = \Pr[g=1|r=1]$$

Fact $1$:
From the previous part we know:
$$\frac12 +\alpha < \Pr[r=g] = \frac12(1-p_0) +\frac12p_1.$$
Some rearranging gets us:
$$p_1-p_0>2\alpha$$

Let $\hat p_0$ and $\hat p_1$ be our estimates of $p_0$ and $p_1$ from sampling some bit strings from $\{0,1\}$. Let $r_i$ be the value of the MSB that the string $x$ had in the $i$th sample. Then for that $i$th sample, we will make a guess for it and denote that guess $g_i$.

Do $m$ samples and then estimate those probabilities as follow:

$$\hat p_0 = \frac1m \sum^m_{i=1} g_i \space \text{ for random bit string $x$ such that } r_i = 0 $$

$$\hat p_1 = \frac1m \sum^m_{i=1} g_i \space \text{ for random bit string $x$ such that } r_i = 1 $$

Fact $2$ (to prove):
Show that for $m>4(\frac\alpha2)^2 (\frac\delta2)$,

$$\Pr \left[|p_0-\hat p_0|<\frac\alpha2\right] > 1 -\frac\delta2$$
$$\Pr \left[|p_1-\hat p_1|<\frac\alpha2\right] > 1 -\frac\delta2$$

[Hint $1$: Law of Large Numbers (LLN) or Chebyshev's inequality]

[Hint $2$: the variance of a r.v. in the range from $0$ to $1$ is upper-bounded by $1/4$]

---

I have tried multiple things; however, I am having troubles applying Chebyshev's or LLN. The thing that confuses me about the hints is that LLN is just an asymptotic result with a limit saying that we approach the true value for large value of samples. I am not sure why Chebyshev or LLN would require the condition that $m>4(\frac\alpha2)^2 (\frac\delta2)$, it seems a bit odd (since Chebyshev is not a result for large values). Also, $\delta$ is never really specified, currently I think they might mean difference between true and estimate; however, I am not sure what it's suppose to mean. Also, some things I have realized is that even though Chebyshev's uses bounds with variances, we don't need the variance because we can bound it by $1/4$. Also, I have used the fact that $\Pr[A]+\Pr[A']=1$ to get the inequality in Chebyshev's pointing in the right direction but I am now not sure how to proceed.

A more general question that I have is, I am a little confused on when in probability bounds/inequality we use statements like $m>{}$(some function) and then a probability or a condition applies?

If anyone knows how to do this or has any ideas what to try out, it would be greatly appreciated! Suggestion of things to do are acceptable answers.

[Note that this is not a homework question.]
[Context: translated from lectures notes for a course I am reading about.]

Comment: "[Note that this is not a homework question.]" OK, it is not. Then what is the context?

Comment: That is a valid question. It comes from the explanation from some lecture notes. They don't really prove fact 2 (but they use it to do more stuff), but it says it can be proved using using the facts I stated. Also, to avoid people having to read those long lecture notes I have translated the question to an equivalent setting by removing some unnecessary details. If people want to see those notes, I can add them to github or something and then let people access them. If you want more context or motivation, I am happy to give more.

Comment: No. "Trying to understand notes for lectures I am following" is sufficient context.

Comment: Now the trouble is the definition of $\hat p_0$ and $\hat p_1$. What is the meaning of "such that ri=0" in "for random ri such that ri=0"? One starts from a collection of $m$ values of $r$ and $m$ values of $g$, I guess, then how to construct $\hat p_0$ from these?

Comment: I think what it means is that, we do m samples of r and denote $r_i$ as the ith sample of distribution from r. But notice that we are trying to estimate conditional probabilities. So for example, for $p_0$, we only count when our prediction  algorithm guesses 1 but $r_i$ is actually 0 and similarly for the other one. We are in control of the sampling and its done fairly, but the algorithm doesn't know the values of r (otherwise we wouldn't be estimating the conditional probabilities correctly). However, we know its values, so we can estimate the conditional probabilities correctly.

Comment: I guess maybe if I would have written "when $r_i$ = 0" we count, it would have been more clear/correct instead of such as?

Comment: Then $\hat p_0\to\frac12p_0$, not $p_0$, hence the bounds cannot hold.

Comment: I think what it boils down to is that I am not sure how to use the probability inequalities (either Chebyshev's or LLN) when m>(some condition). The thing I am unsure is, when do you even need that? The two probability hints they give don't require such a condition, so that confusing. Also, I think we can choose $\delta$ (though, I don't think it has to be a constant).

Comment: I think what it boils down to is that I am quite sure how they want you to use Chebychev (LLN being ludicrous and probably just sloppy writing) but that at he moment the definitions make no sense.

Comment: You are right, the definition of the samples estimates don't make sense. That was my mistake in trying to remove details of the context, let me re-write it.

Comment: but even if they want me to use Chebyshev's, I normally know how to use it, but in this case they added this extra condition on the sample size that doesn't make sense for Chebyshev's, unless I am using the wrong inequality or something.

Comment: @Did I think with the changes I made to the question, it should make sense now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Pinocchio The condition imposed on $m$ is referred to as "finite sample conditions" in statistics. It arises usually when you're using Chebyshev or Chernoff bounds to get concentration results. Think about this way: if the variance of a random variable scales as $1/m$, then the failure probability scales as something like $1/m$. Hence to get failure probability $\delta$ you need $m\gtrsim \delta$.