# Which different probabilistic bounds/inequalities apply when we are given a lower bound on the sample size

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, inequality, law-of-large-numbers

Let m be the sample size and $X_i$ be a r.v. that we sample and define a new r.v. such that:

$$M_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum^m_{i=1}{X_i}$$

My question is, what type of probabilistic inequalities require some limit on the sample size such that the inequalities apply? i.e. something similar to:

$$m>f(\delta) \implies \text{some probabilistic inequality holds}$$

Context:

I am trying to do some question and trying to apply Chebyshev's inequality or the law of large numbers (LLN). I am given that the sample size m should be greater than some bound that they give in terms of an error term that I can choose and some other terms that are not important for this question. My confusion is that the different inequalities I have tried look something like:

$$Pr[|M_m-\mu| \geq \epsilon] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{m \epsilon^2}$$

and it doesn't really require that m must be greater than some value, so I had a suspicion that maybe there is something about Chebyshev's that I don't know or something about LLN that I don't know.

I am looking for a different list of inequalities that apply given some bound on the sample size or something like that. Or a list of the different forms of the LLN and Chebyshev's inequality.

So far I think the only bounds I have found that have explicit conditions on the sample size is something called "convergence" probability i.e.:

For a sequence of r.v. $Y_m$ for every accuracy level $\epsilon$ and confidence level $\delta$ and $m \geq m_0$ (i.e. sufficiently large m) we have:

$$Pr[|Y_m - a|\geq \epsilon] \leq \delta$$

Though I know little about this bound, so if anyone knows its relation to LLN or Chebyshev's it would be awesome! Also, I was unsure how you even relate $m_0$ to the confidence level, how is that manipulation done?

---

If you are interested in seeing what the actual/original question is, I will provide a link to it:

[How to use Chebyshev's inequality or the law of large numbers to a probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637877/how-to-use-chebyshevs-inequality-or-the-law-of-large-numbers-to-a-probability-q)

Comment: I guess you mixed $m$ and $n$. It should be $m$ on the right side of the Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Oh dam, oops typo, sorry different resources use different letters so I had a typo. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Pinocchio: you misunderstood the restrictions in the other question. Probabilistic inequalities are valid for every $m$ but they shall yield the required upper bound only when $m$ is large enough. By the way this is just the way things work when applying Bienaymé-Chebychev as well, always. (...)

Comment: (...) Furthermore, as I explained on the other page, the trouble with the question there is not the restriction on $m$ but the fact that the inequalities you ask to prove are WRONG (a more minor problem being that the LLN is off-topic to get explicit bounds). Especially for large values of $m$, the $\hat p_0$ over there is close to $\frac12p_0$, not $p_0$. Trying to avoid this remark only postpones the moment when the question shall be settled (and it sheds a rather strange light on the way you receive what is being explained to you).

Comment: @Did Thanks Did for your suggestion. I agreed that the question was wrong and addressed it immediately last night where I re-wrote some parts of the question that were wrong as you correctly pointed out. However, unless I am wrong (or the notes are wrong), I believe that the error should have been resolved (and I am not trying to postpone anything). Try reading my question again and if there is still something unclear please pin point me where you think it might be wrong.

Comment: @Did Also, if you still believe it implies it approaches $\frac{1}{2}p_0$ do you mind proving an argument or a proof so that I can see where the formulation of my question fails and so that I can improve it? Thanks so much for your time, its greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Pinocchio Cannot say your attitude is a great incentive to do so. And yes, amazingly, I "still believe" that what I explained holds.

Comment: @Did I am sorry Did if I am frustrating you or making you angry, I really don't mean it in anyway. I am not sure what part of my attitude is bothering you, but I sincerely did think I fixed the problem last night (which I might be wrong). I am doing the best I can, sorry. If you don't want to provide a reason for why it approaches that values its ok, I can go a change the question again until its crystal clear what it means because I also don't want to waste your time or anyone else that might be trying to do answer it.

Comment: @Did also sorry the second comment I wrote came out in a way that offended you, I sincerely did not mean it that way, I am just trying to understand those bounds better and seeing your reasoning might have helped me understand them better or could have helped me rephrase my question better. I am just trying to learn and not waste people's time :)

Comment: @Did Also, note that on the internet or when typing things, sometimes things can came out with the wrong tone that it was meant (which could have been my fault for not reading it carefully before submitting it). Also, as a second comment because I believe you down voted this question, I made this question because I thought the other one might have been very specific to my problem and I thought this related question could be more useful for the community ( and also I am trying to understand those bounds better so ti was helpful for me).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood you correctly, I think [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) and [Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) in addition to Chebyshev's inequality with the [strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) and [weak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) laws of large numbers inequality can help you in the beginning. :)